# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter') JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, axios, use-effect

I have a problem concern filter in JavaScript can't working.
I'm not sure may because API using long time for response

My code :

```
const getDataAll  = () =>{
    const [machines, setMachines] = useState([])
    const getMc = async () =>{
       try {
         const resMc = await axios.get("My API")
         setMachines(resMc.data)
       } catch (err) {
         console.error(err.message)
       }

    useEffect(()=>{
       getMc()
    },[])
    
    const sumData = () =>{
       const filterName = machines.data.filter((el) => el.name == "v10turbo")
    }
}
```

Filter have show this alert in some time.

[image]

And i see time show in browser for API response around 8-9 second follow image below

[image]

I'm not sure if I got it right.
if right please help me with to solve this problem

Comment: You are setting `machines` to be an (empty) array. Arrays don't have a `data` property, hence `marchines.data` will return `undefined`. Maybe you meant to write `machines.filter(...)`.

Comment: How are you calling `sumData`? What is `getDataAll`? Is it meant to be a custom hook?

Comment: @Andy   `sumData` called in `useLayoutEffect`  and  `getDataAll is custom hook

Comment: @FelixKling I tried `machines.filter(...)` but program show `Uncaught TypeError: detailDatas.filter is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code itself is correct. But when your component renders, there is no data yet, useeffect works after rerender. You need a loading state:

> ```
>     const getDataAll  = () =>{
>         const [machines, setMachines] = useState([]);
>         const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
>         const getMc = async () =>{
>            try {
>              const resMc = await axios.get("My API")
>              setMachines(resMc.data)
>              setLoading(false);
>            } catch (err) {
>              console.error(err.message)
>            }
>         finally {
>         setLoading(false);
>         }
>     
>     }
>     
>         useEffect(()=>{
>            getMc()
>         },[])
>         
>         const sumData = () =>{
>            const filterName = machines.data.filter((el) => item.name == "v10turbo")
>         }
>     }
>     if(loading) {
>      return<p>Loading...</p>
> }
> ```

This should fix it.

Comment: Thk, I tried follow your code can working. And I ask a question inside `useEffect` can use `loading` or not  ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to reach, if u use loading inside of useEffect? I didn't catch the question

Answer (score 0):

I not sure, but this can be helpful

```
const sumData = useCallback(() =>{
   const filterName = machines.data?.filter((el) => item.name == "v10turbo")
}, [machines]);
```